# c# how to add a select list items in viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, selectlist

```
ViewBag.Company= new SelectList(db.i_Company(null).OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName), "CompanyID", "CompanyName");
```

This ViewBag contains CompanyID, and CompanyName, but I would like to add an additional line for the default selection. I would like to add something like:

> CompanyID = 0 and CompanyName= "All Companies"

to the list I have.

How can I add a line manually to this ViewBag?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create instance of `SelectList` separately and then insert a new item to 0 the position in it and then assign it to the ViewBag..

Consider doing following.

```
List<SelectListItem> items = db.i_Company(null).OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName).Select(o => new SelectListItem { Value = o.CompanyID, Text = o.CompanyName}).ToList();

items.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "All Companies", Value = "0" }));

ViewBag.Company = new SelectList(items);
```

Comment: HI Chetan, Thanks for the reply but I'm getting "CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.Selectlist' to 'System.Collection.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'" from second line. Do you know any ways to resolve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: @ted sorry about that... I  changed the answer with a different solution. This should help you resolve your issue without any errors.

Comment: No worries! I still see the error from o.CompanyID part. I tried to change to CompanyID.tostring() , but the dropdown is not displaying any value... Thank you for your support! :)